# Notify web page about a plugin new version php

Tags: php, plugins, notifications

I'm developing a web application where users can upload multiple plugins. I want to give an extra value to my app with a feature like wordpress plugin version adviser. I don't know how to deep in this area in order to investigate. I hear someting like "pingtracks", but not sure if this the correct way. Well, that's my doubt, how can I determinate if there is a new plugin  version to uptade?

Thanks in advance.

PS: There is a table in my db with all plugins relevent data like url, author, current version, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each plugin should have a URL for some sort of update manifest.  The resource at that URL should contain information such as currently available versions, and the URLs of files that need to be updated.  This file could be as simple as static JSON data.

Please remember to use HTTPS, so that it is harder to spoof your update site.

Comment: Agreed. But one more thing, should I "request" the plugin info (for example, everytime the plugin repository is visited)? or can the author make a "advise" with new version?

Comment: @manix, A request has to happen.  It's easiest to do this upon initial login.  Also, be sure to have the request give up after a few seconds so that you don't hang the page up in the event the remote site is down.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that user uploads a new plugin, check the "current version" in your DB and compare it with the last same-named plugin uploaded. (create another table for saving needed data for example)